# Importing PST file into Outlook for Mac doesn't import all messages or folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2011

I am attempting to import a large (5 GB) .pst file created in Outlook 2007 for Windows into Outlook 2011 for Mac. When I view the file in Outlook 2007 I have a large number of messages at the top level (e.g. at the "personal folders" level in the picture below) as well as a single `Sent` subfolder into which I've manually sorted messages I've sent.

[image: mail sidebar]

I've followed [the import instructions](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/outlook/item/c1746130-ebef-4312-aa95-950ae8623bf9). After importing I can see the Sent folder, which seems to contain all the messages it should, but at the top-level `Personal Folders` is empty and none of the other messages are in there.

[image]

Why are the other messages not being imported correctly?

---

**Real-time follow-up**

From Windows, I created another `Archive` folder and dragged all the content from the top-level into that subfolder and re-imported. Same result: only a single `Sent` folder and none of the top-level messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an answer as to why the other folder didn't import properly, but I found a work around.

In a Windows-based version of Outlook I opened the PST file and exported everything at the top level but not in the `Sent` folder into a separate PST file. I then separately imported this separate file into Outlook for Mac.